# BLE, comparing Apples to Androids

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth

I have a BLE test device.  I have connected it to three apple products successfully, with bi-directional communication having latency of < 1 second in each direction.  I have also tested four Android devices.  All four Android devices have latency on the order of 5-10 seconds for communication in each direction.

Is Anyone using BLE devices with Android and have success?  I suspect there is a serious problem with BLE in Android given low performance on 100% of Androids tested and high performance on 100% of Apples tested.

Comment: Possibly related: https://atmosphere.anaren.com/wiki/Android_Issues_With_Bluetooth_Low_Energy

Comment: Thank you Morrison!  I am actually using an Anaren device and Anaren showed me that page right before you did.